# How to monitor process status during process lifetime

Tags: linux, unix, pid, ps

I need to track the process status `ps axf` during executable lifetime.
Let's say I have executable main.exec and want to store into a file all subprocess which are called during main.exec execution.

```
 $ main.exec &
 $ echo $! # and redirect every ps change for PID $! in a file.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strace - trace system calls and signals

```
$ main.exec &
$ strace -f -p $! -o child.txt

-f  Trace  child  processes  as  they  are  created  by currently traced processes as a result of the fork(2), vfork(2) and clone(2) system calls. Note that -p PID -f will attach all threads of process PID if it is multi-threaded, not only thread with thread_id = PID.
```

Comment: 'strace' is what I'm looking for. It works perfectly. 
Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't recompile and instrument main.exec, `ps` in a loop is a simple option that may work for you:

```
while true; do ps --ppid=<pid> --pid=<pid> -o pid,ppid,%cpu,... >> mytrace.txt; sleep 0.2; done
```

Then parse the output accordingly.

`top` may also work, and can run in batch mode but not sure if you can get it to dynamically monitor child processes like `ps`. Don't think so.

Comment: currently I'm doing in that way (ps in a loop)